# Fade only top part of div out as it reaches fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, opacity, fade

I'm trying to fade the top part of my content as it reaches a fixed nav bar with a translucent background. I've got it somewhat working, but you'll see 2 problems:

1. All the content fades out, not just what's approaching the fixed nav. Content should fade at a line by line rate.
2. All the content for all the other divs fade about because of the selector class.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks

```
var divs = $('.section').children();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/20) });
});
```

JS Fiddle so far: http://jsfiddle.net/x5JKC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit your code :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.section').each(function (index, item) {
        $(item).children().each(function (indexChild, child) {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            st = $(window).scrollTop() - $(child).offset().top + 10;
            $(child).css({ 'opacity': (1 - st / 20) });
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5JKC/3/

Edit the divisor (20) or remove the +10 to reduce/increase the effect.

Edit: Comment changed the approach to hiding elements (progressive hiding on big element), try then with a gradient acting as a mask and growing down with the scroll :

```
<div class="section red">
    <div class="mask red"> </div>
    <h1>section headline</h1>
    <p>first paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
    <p>third paragraph</p>
</div>

.mask.red{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, rgba(255,0,0,0)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, rgba(255,0,0,0)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, rgba(255,0,0,0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
   background: linear-gradient(red, rgba(255,0,0,0)); /* Standard syntax */
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.section .mask').each(function (index, item) {
            var heightMask = $(window).scrollTop() - $(item).offset().top+90;
        console.log(heightMask);
        $(item).css({height:heightMask});
        });
});
```

Comment: This almost does it. There's some places where I need to select deeper than one level down, so `children()` is clearing everything rather than one element at a time. I tried replacing that with `find()` but I wasn't getting any results. Updated the JS Fiddle to recreate what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/x5JKC/6/

Comment: This isn't displaying any different for me. It's still clearing all the inside elements at once.

Comment: Ha sorry, did not understand you last comment. You want all items fading by itself at any depth of the content?

Comment: Yeah, if that's possible. The issue I'm trying to get around is that sometimes the top half of the content will be shown, but the bottom won't. ie: a tall photo. The bottom should still be at opacity 1 while the top is 0.

Comment: Ok, I changed my approach and worked with a gradient growing down over the text (transparent-color), have a look on the red container. http://jsfiddle.net/x5JKC/11/

Answer (score 2):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x5JKC/13/)

```
var $section = $('.section');
var $window = $(window);
var fadeAt = 150; // start fade ad Npx from top
var zeroAt = 50 ; // Npx from top = 0 opacity

function fadeByApproach(){
    var st = $window.scrollTop();
    $.each($section, function(idx, el){
        var secPos = $(el).offset().top - st;
        if(secPos<fadeAt){       // Ignores other sections
            var $ch = $('*', this); // all elements 
            $.each($ch, function(){
                var top = $(this).offset().top - st;
                if(top<fadeAt){  // Ignores other childrrens
                    var opa = (top-zeroAt)/(fadeAt-zeroAt)/1;
                    $(this).html("TOP: "+top +'<br> Current Opacity: '+ opa);
                    this.style.opacity = opa;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

$(window).on('scroll load resize', fadeByApproach);
```

You might want to run your function on scroll, but also on load and window resize, just like I did.

Comment: In order to avoid performance death, do you have a suggestion on how to fade elements without fading the entire container they've been placed in? They're typically still content being read toward the bottom of the page as the top of the page hits the nav bar.

Comment: @BHOLT done. edited. notice the `if(secPos<fadeAt){` that will prevent our script to look for `*` all descendant elements of sections which position is higher than "the value we're interested in". + I've added a way for you to handle where to start fade your elements and where (top position) to end (zero) the opacity.