# Fade top and bottom part of div on scroll

Tags: jquery

I would like some help to fade out the top and the bottom part of an div on scroll. I got the top part fade working after reading [Fade only top part of div out as it reaches fixed navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978184/fade-only-top-part-of-div-out-as-it-reaches-fixed-navigation) and Yoann's answer but I can't figure out how to do it with the bottom part aswell.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('.section').each(function (index, item) {
        $(item).children().each(function (indexChild, child) {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            st = $(window).scrollTop() - $(child).offset().top + 10;
            $(child).css({ 'opacity': (1 - st / 20) });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: i cant quite tell, so youre trying to fade out the children of ".section" to a certain factor of 1 - st / 20?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way fading one direction of div, top or bottom:

```
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, black 90%, transparent 100%);
```

I am also looking for both. multi linear-gradient does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css gradient that goes from white (or whatever background color) to transparent then back to white. wrap your container in a div and use jquery to add and remove the css class from the div when necessary.

Comment: The background is an image so css gradients are not possible